# Android using java, variable life cycle

Tags: java, android, variables

I  am stuck at a bug,  I have this code:

```
  public String enteredText="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bts_scan = findViewById(R.id.scanning);
        helpButton = findViewById(R.id.helpButton);
        nextPage = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        bts_scan.setOnClickListener(v->{
            openPopupDialog();
        });
        helpButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            contactMail();

        });
        nextPage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            next();
        });


    }

    private void openPopupDialog() {
        Dialog popupDialog = new Dialog(this);
        popupDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
        Button popupButton = popupDialog.findViewById(R.id.popupButton);
        editText = popupDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_the_text_of_scan);

        popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredText = editText.getText().toString();
                if (enteredText.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.e("PopupDialog", "Entered text is empty.");
                } else {
                    Log.d("PopupDialog", "Entered text: " + enteredText);
                    scanCode();
                }
                popupDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        popupDialog.show();
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher=registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(),result -> {
        if(result.getContents() !=null)
        {

            String scan_results = null;
            try {
                scan_results = scanResults(result.getContents(),enteredText);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(page1ScanQRCode.this);
            builder.setTitle("Results");
            builder.setMessage(scan_results);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                        {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

            ).show();
        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(page1ScanQRCode.this);
            builder.setMessage("I can't read that output!!");
            builder.show();
        }
    });

  private void scanCode() {
        ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
        options.setPrompt("Volume up to flash on");
        options.setBeepEnabled(true);
        options.setOrientationLocked(true);
        options.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
        barLauncher.launch(options);
    }
```

The life cycle of my enteredText variable does not last sometimes. Let's say I put as an input on my mobile app "X32E2"  sometimes after pressing the button to scan, my variable gets on null and not retrieving the X32E2 to my scanResults() method, Why? and how can I fix this.

I expected my variable to keep the Value till the end. Sometimes it works, but other times the variable value is null

Comment: If the activity is recreated (e.g. rotating the screen), you will lose all the values because it's a new object instance. This is why you should separate your logic and your UI (look for MVVM or other clean patterns).

Comment: So it is always better to use clean patterns? in any circumstances I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this is the lifecycle of the **`Activity`** in **`Andorid`**.
When the user interacts with your app, **`Android`** can recreate **`activities`** in response to various events. When an **`activity`** is recreated, its state may not be preserved and all member variables are reset to their default values unless you explicitly save and restore it.

In your code, you have declared the **`enteredText`** variable as a **`class`** field, but you're not saving and restoring its state when the activity is recreated. When your **`Activity`** is recreated after you set the value of **`enteredText`**, but before you use it in **`scanResults()`**, then **`enteredText`** would be reset to its default value (null here).

You should save your **`enteredText`** variable in the **`savedInstanceState`** Bundle in the **`onSaveInstanceState()`** method, and then restore it in either **`onCreate()`** or **`onRestoreInstanceState()`**.

```
public String enteredText="";
Button bts_scan, helpButton, nextPage;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bts_scan = findViewById(R.id.scanning);
    helpButton = findViewById(R.id.helpButton);
    nextPage = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        enteredText = savedInstanceState.getString("EnteredText");
    }

    bts_scan.setOnClickListener(v->{
        openPopupDialog();
    });
    helpButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        contactMail();
    });
    nextPage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        next();
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("EnteredText", enteredText);
}

private void openPopupDialog() {
    Dialog popupDialog = new Dialog(this);
    popupDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    Button popupButton = popupDialog.findViewById(R.id.popupButton);
    editText = popupDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_the_text_of_scan);

    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enteredText = editText.getText().toString();
            if (enteredText.isEmpty()) {
                Log.e("PopupDialog", "Entered text is empty.");
            } else {
                Log.d("PopupDialog", "Entered text: " + enteredText);
                scanCode();
            }
            popupDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    popupDialog.show();
}

ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher=registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(),result -> {
    if(result.getContents() !=null)
    {

        String scan_results = null;
        try {
            scan_results = scanResults(result.getContents(),enteredText);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(page1ScanQRCode.this);
        builder.setTitle("Results");
        builder.setMessage(scan_results);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                    {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }

        ).show();
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(page1ScanQRCode.this);
        builder.setMessage("I can't read that output!!");
        builder.show();
    }
});
private void scanCode() {
  ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
  options.setPrompt("Volume up to flash on");
  options.setBeepEnabled(true);
  options.setOrientationLocked(true);
  options.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
  barLauncher.launch(options);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot, I got now the Idea behind it. So the current activity can be closed.... so that's why  we have the onSaveInstanceState to maintain the value there. Thank yuuuu